# google analytics loading time on vue js page

Tags: vuejs2, google-analytics, vue-router

I'm currently building a vue js application that uses a pluging to handle google analytics events and I want to implement the timing_complete event to have data on the loading speed of different pages. The application uses vue router to render content via router-view tags.

Plugging code is the following:

```
var Analytics = function(){}

let Router
let Vue

Analytics.prototype.install(_Vue, _config={}, _Router) {
    Vue = _Vue
    Router = _Router
    
    Vue.$analytics = Vue.prototype.$analytics = Analytics;
    bootstrap()
}
```

where bootsrap loades the gtag global script, and the pluging is used at the project root (main.js) by calling Vue.Use(Analytics).

My question is if I want to measure the loading time of each route, how could I implement it inside the plugging? Would a mixin for the created hook work every time a new route is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Vue navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)—the `afterEach` hook is most suitable—to emit a new pageview event to GA, which will include its own page load time. There is, however, also a Vue Router module called [vue-gtag](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag) that will handle this and more granular analytics configurations for you.

```js
router.afterEach(( to, from ) => {
  ga('set', 'page', to.path);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

Comment: I based my implementation on vue-gtag, but unfortunetly they don't provide an api to directly measure loading time; in their implementation they use that hook but I still don't know how to capture the loading time.

Comment: For that, you would use the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API#calculate_the_total_page_load_time).

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work to compute the time.

Answer (score 0):

To do it the plugging has to inject a global mixin.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin

so the install method has to look something like this:

```
Analytics.prototype.install(_Vue, _config={}, _Router) {
    Vue = _Vue
    Router = _Router
    
    Vue.$analytics = Vue.prototype.$analytics = Analytics;
    Vue.mixin({
        beforeCeate(){
            window.performance.mark("start")
        },
        mounted() {
            window.performance.mark("end")
            ga("timing_complete", window.performance.measure("end", "start").duration)
        }
    })
    bootstrap()
}
```

Following @selfagency commentto incorporate the NavigationTiming api.